# Chefでnot_if条件が実行されない

Tags: chef

Chefでrubyの環境を構築するレシピを作成しておりrbenvとrubyのインストールまではできましたがgemのインストールがうまくいきません。
まだ`bundler`をインストールしていないのにも関わらず`* bash[install bundler] action run (skipped due to not_if)`と表示されてしまいます。

下記にレシピの当該箇所を抜粋します。

```
bash 'install bundler' do
  user 'test_user'
  group 'test_user'
  cwd '/home/test_user'
  environment 'HOME' => '/home/test_user'
  code <<-EOC
    source ~/.bash_profile
    gem install bundler
  EOC
  not_if 'gem list | grep bundler', :environment => { 'HOME' => '/home/test_user'}
end
```

Comment: 有ってそうに見えますけど、`gem list | grep bundler`が期待通りの結果になっていないのかもしれませんね。 気になったのは .bash_profile を読み込んでますが not_if のところでは読み込んで無いので 明示的に読み込ませると何か変化はありますか？

Comment: not_ifの部分に`source ~/.bash_profile;`を追加したらうまくいきました回答ありがとうございました。上記内容回答いただければベストアンサートいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`code`では `.bash_profile` を読み込んでますが `not_if` のところでは読み込んでいないので それが影響している可能性があります。

次のように明示的に `.bash_profile` を読み込んでください。

```
bash 'install bundler' do
  user 'test_user'
  group 'test_user'
  cwd '/home/test_user'
  environment 'HOME' => '/home/test_user'
  code <<-EOC
    source ~/.bash_profile
    gem install bundler
  EOC
  not_if 'source ~/.bash_profile; gem list | grep bundler', :environment => { 'HOME' => '/home/test_user'}
end
```